# How to make an input field mandatory with a default value already present in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a situation where I have an input box and I have some default value already present , I want the user to add something to it before submitting the form , otherwise it should come as required field .

Have tried few things but that hasn't worked for me -

My HTML -

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                            <mat-label>Value <mark *ngIf="isRequired" class="red">*</mark></mat-label>
                            <input formControlName="LinkFull" type="text" matInput autocomplete="off" />
                        </mat-form-field>
```

And in my TS -

```
ngOnInit(){
...
this.form.get('LinkFull').setValue(Constants.DefaultValue);  
}
```

And in some dropdown change I am doing this -

```
if(this.IDSelected == 1 ){
  if(this.form.get('LinkFull').value == Constants.DefaultValue){
    this.form.get('LinkFull').setValidators(Validators.required);
    this.form.get('LinkFull').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.isRequired = true;
  }
  else{
    this.form.get('LinkFull').clearValidators();
    this.form.get('LinkFull').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.isRequired = false;
  }
}
else{
    this.form.get('LinkFull').clearValidators();
    this.form.get('LinkFull').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.isRequired = false;
}
```

But still on submit of form this field is not taken up as a required field . Can anyone help how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create custom validator to check for the default value and use it verify the input

```
export class customValidators{
    public static requiredWithDefault(defaultValue: string) {
            return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
                if (control.value == defaultValue)
                    return { defaultValue: 'value '+defaultValue+' is the default value' }
                return null;
            }
        }
}
```

then use it on contol defination like

```
this.form=new FormGroup({
...,
LinkFull:new FormControl(Constants.DefaultValue,[customValidators.requiredWithDefault(Constants.DefaultValue)]),
...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `LinkFull` already has a value, it's not resulting in an error due to the required validator that you have used. You can create your custom validator such as:

```
  static requiredNonDefault(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
      return (!control.value || control.value === Constants.DefaultValue) ? { required: true } : null;
    };
  }
```

and use that instead:

```
ngOnInit(){
...
this.form.get('LinkFull').setValidators(requiredNonDefault());  
}
```